# How do I add waze incident markers to a google maps javascript API-generated map with traffic?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, traffic, waze

I created a map showing traffic with the google maps javascript API using the TrafficLayer object. A googlmaps.com-generated map of the same area displays waze incident icons, but they do not show up on my map. Is there a way to include the incident markers when generating the traffic map? Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 37.794086, lng: -122.400445},
      zoom: 12
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present it is impossible to add layer with incidents / constructions markers on the google traffic map.

Discussion on this topic takes place since 2010 and is available on the site:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2411

It remains to wait for the response of the google developers.